Expected size of "Minkowski reflection" of a random subset of $w \times w$ grid about another, given their sizes?
For $U$,$V$ sets of points on Cartesian plane, define the "Minkowski reflection" $U \star V$ of $U$ about $V$ as the set of positions occupied by reflections of every point in $U$ about every point in $V$.
Let $S$ be the Cartesian product of the set of first $N$ natural numbers with itself (understood as point coordinates), and $S_a$, $S_b$ its two random nonempty subsets. Let $a=\frac{|S_a|}{N^2}$, $b=\frac{|S_b|}{N^2}$ be their respective shares in $S$.
What is $\text{F}(a,b,N)$, the expected value of $\frac{|S_a \star S_b|}{(3N-2)^2}$ for given $N$?
EDIT: did some elementary probability work on this. It is a high degree polynomial, expressible using $\text{P}(u,W)$, a polynomial in $u = 1-ab$ with $W=N-1$, built in the following manner (if I didn't make any mistakes, but Monte Carlo seems to check out):
Using:
$$
W=N-1
$$
$$
\text{c}(k,W) = \max(0,\lfloor\min(W,\frac{x+W}{2})\rfloor - \lceil \max(0,\frac{x}{2})\rceil + 1)
$$
Then the coefficients $\text{v}(n,W)$ are given as distinct value occurrence counts:
$$
\text{v}(n,W) = |\{(i,j) \in [-W,2W]\times[-W,2W] : \text{c}(i,W)\text{c}(j,W) = n\}|
$$
Then (keeping in mind that $\text{v}(n,W)≠0$ for finitely many $n$):
$$
\text{P}(u,W) = (3W)^{-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\text{v}(n,W)(1-u^n)
$$
and:
$$
\text{F}(a,b,N) = \text{P}(1-ab,N-1)
$$
What I would like to know is whether there is a simple and accurate approximation for this kind of polynomials using transcendental functions. The motivation for this is that $\text{P}(1-x^2,W)$ (the $a=b$ case to which the problem reduces) doesn't look much like a polynomial when plotted. It looks more like the birthday paradox curve that rushes quickly towards 1 but reaches it only at $x=1$. Unfortunately when something doesn't look like a polynomial, it is usually hard to approximate with one, and that includes "polynomials that don't look like polynomials", for which simply discarding higher degree terms doesn't work very well.
